# iOS/Objective-C: Creating a UIScrollView which fills screen and reorients

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, resize, fill

I'm trying to achieve the simplest thing - creating a UIScrollView which fills (and exactly fits) the application frame (i.e. screen minus status bar height) regardless of device orientation.

This is proving very challenging though - the scroll view seems reluctant to resize correctly in landscape view, and I'm not sure why.

I decided to forget about using the application frame and simply attempt to fill the screen, ignoring status bar height, yet even this hasn't been possible.

You can see the approach I'm using below. Would anyone be kind enough to demonstrate how to do this correctly? I seem to permanently run into issues with sizing objects correctly, especially when attempting to fill the iPhone/iPad screen entirely.

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    CGFloat viewedWidth, viewedHeight;
    const CGSize dim = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)) {
        viewedWidth = dim.width;
        viewedHeight = dim.height;
    } else {
        viewedWidth = dim.height;
        viewedHeight = dim.width;
    }
    [self.scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, viewedWidth, viewedHeight)];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.view setFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1,1)];
    [self.scrollView setDelegate:self];        
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:sizeManager.canvasSize];
    [self didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]; // NOTE: orientation passed is not used, dummy
}
```

Your advice is most welcome, many thanks.

Comment: for getting the frame your view is able to use, you can take this: `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would avoid trying to determine the size yourself; just let iOS do the work for you:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIScrollView *sv = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    sv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:sv];
    [sv release];
}
```

This will ensure that the scroll view will always be resized along with its container view.

Comment: Thanks very much odrm, that does the trick :) I have a follow-up question, if you don't mind: when specifying the content size for a scrollview, should I be setting the frame of the scrolling subview to be that dimension as well? I'm laying out views programmatically rather than using Interface Builder and haven't found a suitable example online. I should add that the subview I'm scrolling contains no UIKit components, instead it has a custom drawRect implementation for manual drawing. This is why I'm unsure of whether to set its bounds/frame..